# Compute the Taylor Series for $f\left(x\right)=\ln\left(1+x^2\right)$ about $x= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I'm very confused by this question.  Can you provide me with hints as to how to get started with this one?

> $f\left(x\right)=\ln\left(1+x^2\right)$ about $x= 0$

Do I just use the Taylor Series formula and plug-n-chug?

Comment: Have you tried the elementary way, via Taylor's theorem?

Comment: Can you expand $f'(x)=2x/(1+x^2) = 2x \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as a power series?

Comment: Take the series of $\log(1+y)$ and replace $y$ by $x^2$

Comment: @CatalinZara this is the hint we were given!  What do you mean by "expanding" it?

Comment: Such as $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1-x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + ...$ (sum of a geometric series with first term 1 and ratio $-x^2$.

Comment: @CatalinZara sorry if this is a silly question, but what happened to the $2x$

Comment: That was just the second term. Multiply by $2x$ to get $f'(x)$. Then integrate term by term and use the value of $f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any continuous and differentiable function Taylor's theorem can be used to approximate a function at any given point c and will converge to some radius r (diverge if r approaches infinity). However if you were to calculate the Taylor series for the ln(1+y) and set y = x^2 you will get a new series that converges when y converges. (The radius will change upon substitution and will need to be reevaluated)

Comment: Why should he need a change of variable ?

Comment: It was just a suggestion to further simplify the action of taking derivatives. @YvesDaoust

Comment: I know, but it might be of interest to the OP to know the reason for this detour .